# Using old() function with another default value for input in blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I tried to use two default value for a input with condition in blade:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="wallet" name="wallet" value="{{old('wallet') or 0}}">
```

I want the old() to be use when the inputs value is incorrect and the other should be used when the page is open for the first time and for is not submitted yet, but when i run the code the `0` as default value is not set in input.Where is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-old) can have a second parameter for default value. So you can use, `old('wallet', 0)`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the solution to you question so other users might also find this.

Comment: This works fine for if you just have two potential parameters so is fine for this use case however if OP wanted to use more than one potential option eg. if editing a model, you could null coalesce (??) operator like so : `old('value') ?? $model->value ?? $defaultValue`

Comment: @KyleWardle why not `old('value', $model->value ?? $defaultValue)` ?

Comment: @Robert That is true actually, I guess the only situation where that would not be quite enough would be if you wanted the `$model->value` to take priority over the old value as with this current method it will always prioritise the `old('value')`